# Reversing all characters on each line of a range

Tags: vimscript

In order to invert all characters on each line of a range I could think of the following

```
:s/.*/\=list2str(reverse(str2list(getline('.'))))"
```

where I can put a `[range]` if I want.

Is there any better way to do this? I mean, quicker to write/more performant/more versatile.

Comment: Write a function that accept a range and do what you want and then define a visual mode mapping for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on Linux, you probably have `rev` installed.

Then you can do:

```
:2,5!rev
```

Where 2,5 is range.

Comment: Even if it's not technically Vim, it's the perfect solution, I think.

Answer (score 2):

A slight improvement

```
:[range]s/.*/\=join(reverse(split(submatch(0), '\zs')), '')/
```

The use of `submatch` allows this to to be more flexible, e.g.,

```
:[range]s/hello: \zs.*/\=join(reverse(split(submatch(0), '\zs')), '')/
```

We use `split`/`join` because the `str2list` approach will fail with combining characters, for example;

```
echo list2str(reverse(str2list('áb')))
```

prints

```
b́a
```